# Wordpress, random product only on home search page

Tags: php, wordpress, search, random

I have a custom wordpress search page with page navigation numbers, my client asks me to random products on page 1 but not for others, but all products displayed randomly on home page should not displayed on others pages.

For the query i have this code :

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'products',
  'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
)
```

and for the random :

```
if( $args['paged'] == 1) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
} else {
    $args['order'] = 'DESC':
}
```

the results are there when i do a search, and first page random well, but some products that are already displayed on home page because of the random are also displayed on others pages (ex : page 2 ).

The aim is not display products that are already displayed on home page.

I already do something similar :

```
if( $page == 1 ) shuffle($r->posts);
```

But it shuffle only first the 10 products on page 1, and others products on others pages never display on page 1.

After some thoughts i think store first 10 random products to cookie or session and do a NOT IN for others pages ? like this ?

```
if( $args['paged'] == 1 ){
                        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';

                        $r = new Wp_Query($args);
                        $randomFirstPage = wp_list_pluck( $r->posts, 'ID' );
                        print_r($randomFirstPage);
                        setcookie( 'firstPageResults', $randomFirstPage, time()+3600, '/', 'mydomain.com/dev' );

                    }else{
                        $not_in = $_COOKIE['firstPageResults'];
                        $args['NOT IN'] = $not_in;
                        $r = new Wp_Query($args);

                    }
```

Sorry for bad english, and may you help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this aproach:

```
<?php 
$products1_ids = array();
$products2_ids = array();
$allproducts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'products'));

$p=1; foreach($allproducts as $products) {
    if(is_page(1) && $p<11) {
       $products1_ids[] = $products->ID;
    }
    if(!is_page(1) && $p>10) {
       $products1_ids[] = $products->ID;
    }
$p++; }
shuffle($products1_ids);
shuffle($products2_ids);


$post_in = is_page(1) ? $products1_ids : $products2_ids;  
$products = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__in' => $post_in,
));

if($products->have_posts()) {
    while($products->have_posts()) { $products->the_post();
       echo '<div class="post">'
           the_title();
       echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code above uses `$args['NOT IN'] = $not_in;`, but according to the [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) the argument to exclude posts by id is `post__not_in`:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__not_in' => array(2, 5, 12, 14, 20))
);
```

So try:

```
$args['post__not_in'] = $not_in;
```